# Sending and receiving image via bluetooth iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

How to send and receive image via bluetooth on iOS/Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to use the Gamekit APIs for iOS to iOS devices.
This is a good tutorial - http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502